# How To Make Post To A External API With Methods And Data By Dart

Tags: json, api, post, dart, flutter

I Have A Web Service And Want To Post Data By Flutter Dart json In My WebService API Link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For REST API calls I prefer to use a library named [Dio](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio). Its way too easy to make GET, POST, PUT, DELETE etc calls using Dio.

For Example

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

   //Now like this

void _makeApiCall() async {
   Dio dio = new Dio();
   Response apiResponse = await dio.get('${YOUR URL}?id=$id'); //Where id is just a parameter in GET api call
   print(apiResponse.data.toString());
}
```

And If you want to make a POST call and you need to send Form data with that do like this

```
void _makeApiCall() async {
   Dio dio = new Dio();
   FormData formData = FromData.from({
    name : "name",
    password: "your password",
   }); // where name and password are api parameters
   Response apiResponse = await dio.post('${YOUR URL}', data: formData); 
   print(apiResponse.data.toString());
}
```

Also you can map the received data into so called POJOs for better handling and usage.
If you want to know how to map the data into POJO (Objects), Just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

you need to be more specif about the API and what you want to send. this is a simple example from the [HTTP client library](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http)

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var url = "http://example.com/whatsit/create";
http.post(url, body: {"name": "doodle", "color": "blue"})
    .then((response) {
  print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
  print("Response body: ${response.body}");
});

http.read("http://example.com/foobar.txt").then(print);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide more details on the API?

Imagine your API takes data like so, http://localhost:3000

You can make the request as follows

```
  Future<String> create(String text) async {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    try {
      HttpClientRequest req = await client.post('localhost', 3000, '/');
      req.headers.contentType = new ContentType("application", "json", charset: "utf-8");
      req.write('{"key":"value"}');
      HttpClientResponse res = await req.close();
      if (res.statusCode == HttpStatus.CREATED) return await res.transform(UTF8.decoder).join();
      else throw('Http Error: ${res.statusCode}');
    } catch (exception) {
      throw(exception.toString());
    }
}
```

**OR**

If you would like to post a Map (created from whatever json you have), you can use the `http` package. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

```
String url = "http://example.com/whatsit/create";
http.post(url, body: {"name": "doodle", "color": "blue"})
    .then((response) {
  print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
  print("Response body: ${response.body}");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this packages [dio package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio)

doing post will be like this :

```
Future<List> postDataFromURL_list(String url, Map map) async {
    // TODO: implement postDataFromURL_list
    Response response;
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    FormData formData = new FormData.from(map);

    response = await dio.post(url, data: formData);

  }
```